# IBM Cloud - appsettings not recognized

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, ibm-cloud

I am deploying an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API in the IBM Cloud, and it is failing when I try to access the database, because `appsettings` is not loaded correctly.

I noticed that because when I switch connection string to environment variable, it works fine. I am new to the IBM Cloud, is there anything specific that I need to set on deployment to include `appsettings`?

I am using only `appsettings.json`, there is no additional json files or environment variables.

I have tried adding environment variables, but I need `appsettings.json`.